# How to find a string match within a subject for this pattern {{ @sql( query ) }}

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am trying to find a pattern match using php.

My string contains something like this

```
{{ @sql( select [name] from [table] where [col1] = 50 AND [col2] = :alt_id_1 AND [col3] = :id  ) }}
```

I would need to return the following data

1. The portion the string that matches
2. The string that comes between `{{@sql(` and `)}`
3. Any keyword that starts with colon `:`

For example, if I have the following string

```
$subject = 'Hello This is a test. The value found is "{{ @sql( select [name] from [table] where [col1] = 50 AND [col2] = :alt_id_1 AND [col3] = :id  ) }}".';
```

Then for the first bullet I will need to return `{{ @sql( select [name] from [table] where [col1] = 50 AND [col2] = :alt_id_1 AND [col3] = :id  ) }}`

For the second bullet I would need to return `select [name] from [table] where [col1] = 50 AND [col2] = :alt_id_1 AND [col3] = :id`

For the last bullet, I would return an array with `:alt_id_1` and `:id`

Here is what I tried

```
$pattern = '/\{\{\s*+@sql(*)+\s*+\}\}/i';
$matches = [];
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches );
echo '</pre>';
```

But it is giving me an exception

```
preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can not capture repeating subpatterns** with PREG and most other regex syntax.

So, you can try this:

```
$pattern = '/\{\{\s*+@sql\((.+(\:[^ ]+))+.*\)+\s*+\}\}/i';
```

but `preg_match_all` will capture **only last subpattern**.
If you known in advance that all subjects will have exactly the same number of `:xxx` substrings, you can set the pattern in this way:

```
$pattern = '/\{\{\s*+@sql\((.+(\:[^ ]+).+(\:[^ ]+).*)\)+\s*+\}\}/i';
```

Otherwise, you have to run two different `preg_match`:

```
$pattern1 = '/\{\{\s*+@sql\((.+)\)+\s*+\}\}/i';
$pattern2 = '/:[^ ]+/i';

preg_match    ( $pattern1, $subject,       $matches,   PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );
preg_match_all( $pattern2, $matches[1][0], $repeating, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );
```

<kbd>**[eval.in demo](https://eval.in/509146)**</kbd>

#### Edit:

From official [PHP Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php):

> When a capturing subpattern is repeated, the value captured is the substring that matched the final iteration

Comment: Thank you so much that did it

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses are special characters. So if you want literal parentheses you should escape them

```
$pattern = '/\{\{\s*+@sql\([^\)]*\)\s*+\}\}/i';
```

Changed `(*)+` to `\([^\)]*\)`

The compilation error is from `)+` since it doesn't recognize `)` as a valid character for a repeater (`+`).

Comment: this solved the error and found the whole string aka bullet 1. How can I get bullet 2 and 3 out of the same pattern?